# C# SuperSimpleTCP: Received file is partially corrupted

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm working on file transferring application based on TCP (SuperSimpleTCP). The application should allow file transfer between computers within LAN. And it partially does so - problem is, the received file is partially corrupted (see the screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Sec.jpg).

The top of the image is always saved correctly, however the rest of the image is corrupted at random points - can be half way down or just few pixels below the top. I don't quite understand why is that happening.

I though that the problem might lay either in way received packages are assembled or data packages not getting to the server at all (despite TCP).

So I tried different methods of assembling 'em at the server site, like collecting them into an List and then rewriting to a byte[] and finally saving. Also I made the client sent "ack" message when the last pieces of file were sent, allowing the server to save the file.

However, none of mentioned above changed the way the file is behaving.

This is the code in client class, responsible for sending the file:

```
 public async void SendFile(string path)
            {
               
                var size = new FileInfo(path).Length;
               
                SendMessage($"FILE:{Path.GetFileName(path)}:{size}");
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await client.SendAsync(size, fs); // SendAsync is a SSTCP method
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File sent.");
            }
```

This is the code in server class responsible for receiving and saving the file.

```
private void EventsOnDataReceived(object? sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New content received: " + e.Data.Length + " Bytes.");
            string message;
            var content = e.Data;
            if (content.Length <= 128) // messages are shorter than 128 bytes
            {
                message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);
                if (message.Contains("FILE:"))
                {
                    _filename = message.Split(":")[1]; // class field containing filename
                    _size = long.Parse(message.Split(":")[2]); // class field con. size
                    return;
                }
            }

            // data bigger than 128 bytes is considered a file (for now)
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_filename, FileMode.Append))
            {
                fs.Write(content);
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

** EDIT: posting new version of code at the request of @RowanSmith **

The SendFile method:

```
public async Task SendFile(string path)
            {
                var size = new FileInfo(path).Length;
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await client.SendAsync(size, fs);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File sent.");
            }
```

The server's receiving code:

```
private void EventsOnDataReceived(object? sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New content received: " + e.Data.Length + " Bytes.");

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.png", FileMode.Append))
            {
                fs.Write(e.Data);
            }  
        }
```

Comment: How are you signaling that the transfer is complete?  How are you signalling the length of the file to the server?

Comment: @RowanSmith They send the size via `SendMessage($"FILE:{Path.GetFileName(path)}:{size}");` before the `Thread.Sleep( 200 );`. At least I think that's what `SendMessage` does.

Comment: Probably 200ms isn't long enough to wait unless you're setting NoDelay.  And even then that's a bad way to do it.  Create a proper framing protocol to carry the traffic the header information.  Recognise that TCP is a stream, it looks just like a file on a disk, read until you don't get anymore data, then keep trying to read for a specific timeout, when the timeout expires, treat it just like the file on the disk became corrupt and was truncated early.

Comment: Use `async Task` instead of async void.  Use `await Task.Delay` instead of Thread.Sleep() - but really you should not delay.

Comment: @RowanSmith Presented version is deprived of transfer-complete-signaling feature. This is because - as I mentioned in post - it had no influence on the file, so I removed it and simplified the code. Now The moment package is received by the server it's saved 
( the line with: using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_filename, FileMode.Append)))

I should have calrify that in my post, sorry for that.

Comment: I will also point out that there are a 1000 edge cases in socket programming.  You'd be much better off to use a already established transport service, that's worked out all the edge cases,  rather than writing your own.  I would recommend grpc.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Don't test for 128bytes.  Just read until you hit the second `:` of course assuming that `:` will never be in the filename.  And then read the long.  Then you have the filename and the length of the remaining bytes to read.  You are truncating any bytes received in the first read.  I would recommend using `NULL` as a separator instead of `:`

Comment: @RowanSmith For now I'd like to avoid using and implementing technologies that I don't understand. My goal is to write a simple application with readable and easy to present code. The edge cases are not my primary concern (for now) because this is not a production code.

Comment: Well this is the first edge case you are dealing with - so you need to write the code to deal with it.  That edge case is that you cannot control when/what a computer will put into a TCP packet.

Comment: @RowanSmith The problem with reading until hitting ':' is that I do not use standard networkStream.Read(), but a SuperSimpleTCP event, that is triggered when a data is received. Therefore I have no control over the way data is read or way it is split into packages.

Comment: How do you know how long: `$"FILE:{Path.GetFileName(path)}:{size}` is?  You need to know exactly how many bytes this is so you can extract ONLY those bytes from the stream.  If you extract anymore you will be extracting some of your file, if you extract too few you will have the wrong file length.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Generally speaking that line should never exceed 128 bytes. This might be quite naive, but it works for my case. I did some simple tests to see if parsing is correct and it indeed was: both file name and size were correctly parsed so I did not see this as a problem.

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that.  You cannot be assured that the data received will only contain the bytes that you are interested in.  You need a framing protocol of your own that runs over the TCP.  You have no control over the TCP stack and how it sends packets.

Comment: @RowanSmith Well, honestly, writing a whole new protocol for such a simple application seems like a overkill. I'm not even sure where to start. Also, as I mentioned above, I do not have control over the way the data is split or even send. I guess I could do something like FILE:<lenght_of_message>:<file_name>:<file_size>, but then what about the data packages themselves? SimpleTCP limits my way of interacting with them, so I cannot e.g. append a header to one.

Comment: You have e.Data that is the Data that you have received from the TCP stack at that point in time.  It might or might not be all of the Data you are interested in, you have no way of controlling this.  What if it has too much data?  What if it has too little data?  For a 10KB file this event could get thrown once or 1000 times.

Comment: Consider what happens if this event is fired 100 times and ANY of those times e.Data is < 128 bytes?  Consider what happens if the last time this event fires e.Data is < 128 bytes.

Comment: Well I think that SuperSimpleTCP somehow manages the data for me, so I always get nicely prepared packages: https://imgur.com/a/sB3czSS

Comment: No that doesn't happen unfortunately.  SSTCP is not a messaging protocol - for that you need to use something like grpc or WCF, or roll your own, eg use XML messages.  SSTCP is just a stream of data.  You need to know what format that data is in, when the bytes stop and when they start.

Comment: My Suggestion id dont use low level tcp at all, use a modern messing service like signalr, or anything else, including reliable messaging like busses, or any other framework like grpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occuring because you are receiving data while the you are already receiving data.  The event:

`private void EventsOnDataReceived(object? sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)`

Is being thrown while the previous event is still writing data to the disk.  This is because the disk access is slower then the memory access.

To solve this you need to read the file into memory and then save the file to disk.

The following full example works and it only works because the memory is faster than the reading from the disk.  If your disk because faster than memory, (unlikely), then this would also break.

```
class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = StartServer();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _ = StartClient();

        await server;
        Console.WriteLine("Server exited");
    }

    static MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
    static private void EventsOnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        memoryStream.Capacity = memoryStream.Capacity + e.Data.Length;
        memoryStream.Write(e.Data);
    }

    static async Task StartServer()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        var server = new SimpleTcpServer("127.0.0.1:9999");
        server.Events.DataReceived += EventsOnDataReceived;
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit the server - but wait for the client to finish!");
        Console.ReadKey();

        using FileStream fs = new FileStream("outfile.png", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }

    static async Task StartClient()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        using (SimpleTcpClient client = new SimpleTcpClient("127.0.0.1:9999"))
        {
            using FileStream fs = new FileStream("startfile.png", FileMode.Open);
            client.Connect();
            client.Send(fs.Length, fs);
            client.Disconnect();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Client finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I'm not. I have faith in SSTCP, it really does not even give me ways to check for that, so I suppose it deals with it on its own.

2. It does not. It also does not quit, just runs in separate thread and waits till I kill application.

I added both, Task.Delay and Flush - no change.

Comment: But I've observed something interesting: when original file and corrupted one are opened and compared with each other with notepad++, It seems like data is there, but somehow... shifted?
screen shot here: https://imgur.com/a/uxxuf5J
The dark grey fields mean that code there is the same, the light gray mean "empty space" and the blue one show places where code differs.

Comment: Were you sure to delete the file before appending to it?

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is with your code now.  The issue is that the events are thrown when you are still in the write mode.  I am going to guess that you are doing this on a single computer?  If you were doing this across a network then it would probably work.  The file becomes corrupted because you are receiving more data while the file is open for writing.  When you read the file into memory first, it works because there is no latency accessing the disk subsystem.

Comment: Ok, I have written a full version above that works 100%.  You need to save the file into memory before writing it to disk if you want to do it like this.  If your files are too big for your memory then you need to create a framing protocol to sit on top of SuperSimpleTcp

Comment: Well, you're right. I just ran the goddamn thing on 2 PCs and it actually sent the picture, although I feel like mp3 file had a tiny artifact at one point, or maybe I'm just too tired. 
I guess it worked form the beginning. I'm too sleepy and tired to think now how can I solve this problem locally, but nonetheless thank you very much for your time, the help and patience.

Comment: The code I have above solves it locally.  I can't reiterate enough that you are reinventing a framing protocol for transferring files.

Comment: Well it's still broken: https://imgur.com/a/KHAlG7R - I'm quite sure that my SATA SSD is much slower than my DDR4 3200 MHz memory stick so it has to be something else. And yes I made sure the client finished it's job before killing the server. Nonetheless this is very interesting.

Comment: It works perfectly on my Linux machine, which has similar components. What on earth is happening here?!

Comment: It's SuperSimpleTcp - it just isn't designed for this use case.  EventsOnDataReceived() isn't called in a ThreadSafe way. You could  queue the events into a queue and then dequeue them.  The amount of data you are sending overwhelms the Eventhandler, if you sent 1000bytes at a time and waited 500ms between each send it would probably work - but you're really then hacking your program to work around the limitations of SSTCP.  Really look at grpc - it is super simple, as simple as SSTCP and is PERFECT for what you want to do here.

Comment: Well, my thinking is that "If I can't build it, I don't understand it". Using grpc or any other framework is what I consider cheating. I've only decided to use SSTCP because I was frustrated with numerous bugs (mostly related to cross-platform nature of my app) that halted my progress. At the point of writing the question my goal was to make a working cross-platform prototype, then analyze SSTCP's code that made it possible and then implement my own class doing the same thing, but written by me. I tried and I failed. But I've seen people doing it so I know it's possible, so I'm not giving up.

Comment: I even tried it using a queue in the event handler.  Events still get processed out of order.  The framework you have chosen to use is just not compatible with what you're trying to do.  If you want to continue using this framework then either (a) break the files into 1000byte chunks and send them encoded with their position, this way your program knows how to reassemble them and knows where they go; or (b) delve into the SSTCP source code and make the events queue, and stops events from being thrown again, until the previous event is marked as processed; or (c) roll your own framework.